# NodeJS: How to wait for the HTTP Get request is complete in For Loop?

Tags: node.js

I have a for loop function in NodeJS. I would like to wait until the result of Http Get request is completed in For Loop before it executes the next iteration, how do I achieve that?

```
for (let k=0; k<fd.length; k++) {
    url = fd[k].nct_id;

    HttpSearch({condition: url}).then(trials => {
         //Get the result first before execute the next iteration
         console.log(trials);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the for-loop `async`:

```
const main = async () => {
  for (let k = 0; k < fd.length; k++) {
    const url = fd[k].nct_id;

    const trials = await HttpSearch({ condition: url });

    console.log(trials);
  }
};

main().catch(console.error);
```

This will cause the loop to "pause" at each `HttpSearch`.

Answer (score 0):

I will do like this

```
let k = 0 ;
let len = fd.length;
for (; k > len;) { 
  let url = fd[k].nct_id;
  let subs = await HttpSearch({condition: url});
  console.log(subs);
  k++
}
```

or like this with promise

```
let url;
let promiseChain = Promise.resolve();
for (let i = 0; i < fd.length; i++) { 
    url = fd[k].nct_id;

    // you need to pass the current value of `url`
    // into the chain manually, to avoid having its value
    // changed before the .then code accesses it.

    const makeNextPromise = (url) => () => {

         HttpSearch({condition: url})
            .then((result) => {
                // return promise here
                return result
            });
    }

    promiseChain = promiseChain.then(makeNextPromise(url))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using recursion, which calls next, once previous is finished

```
var limit = fd.length;
var counter = 0;

HttpSearch({condition: fd[0].nct_id;}).then(yourCallBack);

function yourCallBack(trials){
    console.log(trails);
    if(counter == limit)
        return console.log('Done')
    HttpSearch({condition: fd[counter].nct_id;}).then(yourCallBack);
    counter++;
}
```